# Using reference datatypes for a parameter of a method or constructor

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and need help understanding ways to **pass reference datatypes for a parameter of a method or constructor**

Oracle's J2SE tutorial says:

> In this example, the method creates a new Polygon object and initializes it from an array of Point objects (assume that Point is a class that represents an x, y coordinate):

```
public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners) {  
    // method body goes here
}
```

But it's not helping me understand this concept. A detailed explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check these links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319537/how-do-i-pass-a-primitive-data-type-by-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code, the Polygon would be as such:

```
Point[] points = new Point[]{new Point(1,1), new Point(2,2)};
Polygon p = polygonFrom(points);
```

except with your array of corners inside of the parenthesis.

This basically gives the `polygonFrom` function the `points` array and does with it what it pleases. However, whatever the `polygonFrom` method does will not actually change the original `points` array, but it will create its own for it to manipulate.

For example, lets say I have code like so:

```
String s = "Cheeseburger";
sayString(s);
```

and a method:

```
public void sayString(String par1)
{
    par1 = par1 + "1";
    System.out.println(par1);
}
```

This output: `Cheeseburger1`, but the String `s` is still only `Cheeseburger`.

If you need any further clarification, just ask.

EDIT:
Paul Bellora pointed out that there are some circumstances in which the `polygonFrom` method can change the `points` array and I will try to explain that here. However, if this doesn't make any sense, then you shouldn't worry about it quite yet (all of this is a lot to take in).

The `polygonFrom` method can change any variable within its own method and within the class as a whole. Therefore, if the `points` array was initialized outside of a method (i.e. outside of the `main` method), the `polygonFrom` method could change the `points` array, but only if the code inside of the `polygonFrom` method says to directly change that variable. I hope this makes sense.

For example, in the class:

```
Point[] points;

public MethodAccess()//constructor
{
    points = new Point[]{new Point(1,1), new Point(2,2)};
    Polygon p = polygonFrom(points);
}

public Polygon polygonFrom(Point[] corners){

    //doing stuff with corners variable here

    points = corners; //this will change the points variable that was passed

}
```

The constructor will send `polygonFrom` the `points` variable, but the `polygonFrom` gets the variable and creates a new instance of it. The `polygonFrom` method now changes its newly created `corners` variable that has the same values as `points` originally. However, if the method `polygonFrom` specifically says to change the `points` variable, then it will technically change the variable that the constructor sent to it.

Comment: This answer is misleading because the contents of an array *could* be modified by a method it was passed into. I think the point you're trying to make is that the reference to the array could be reassigned in the method, and the reference at the call site would still point to the original array object.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks! You are right. I added in a section to explain that, but I'm not sure if I explained very well.

Comment: @Ionnez Thanks a ton for your time. I know I'm asking a lot.. but I'm a pure stater. Can you explain the same with your own example..? Thanks

Comment: @SnackySrikanth I hope the new example is useful and it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, check the below code -

```
public void a() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    b(list);
}

public void b(List<String> list) {
    list.add("something");
}
```

Method a() creates a list and passes its reference to method b() so that b() can modify the contents of the list. So in this case, the list is the same, just that its reference is passed around. A copy of the list is NOT made here.

Hope this helps.