# Why does boolean change value in method in java

Tags: java

I would like to know why if I set eq = false in the secondPart method then change it to true in the removeAccess method(for the System.out.println shows that eq = true) but then back in the secondPart() the System.out.println shows that eq = false?

```
 public void secondPart(){
    boolean eq = false; 
    removeAccess(copy,d,eq);
    System.out.println(eq);
 }


private void removeAccess(List<Integer> copy, Integer letterNum,boolean eq){
for(int i =0; i<copy.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("LetterNum:" + letterNum);
        System.out.println("Copy:" + copy.get(i));
        if(letterNum == copy.get(i)){

            copy.remove(letterNum);
            eq = true;
            break;
        }

        else{
            eq = false;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Eq:" + eq);


}
```

Comment: because parameters are passed by value in Java

Comment: FIY: `letterNum` is an `Integer` not an `int`. `Integer` should be compared by using `equals` instead of `==`. For example `if(letterNum.equals(copy.get(i)))`. `==` normally compares either the value (if the variables are primitives like `int`) or the reference when they are `Objects`.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi everybody's answer was fine but I like yours the best for it really answered my question of why it won't work. Thanks

Comment: @Rika I will post it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to achieve *pass by reference*: you want `eq` in your method to *refer to* the same boolean that was passed in. But Java has no pass by reference. It only has *pass by value*: the value of `eq` is copied into a new variable that is discarded after the method finishes executing.

Answer (score 3):

In `removeAccess`, your `eq` variable is a copy of the `eq` from `main`.  Changing `removeAccess`'s `eq` does not change `eq` in `main`.

If you want the value `eq` from `removeAccess`, then you must return it.  There is no need to pass it as a parameter; remove the `boolean` parameter.

```
private boolean removeAccess(List<Integer> copy, Integer letterNum) {
    boolean eq = false;
    // rest of code from your method remains the same
    return eq;
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
eq = removeAccess(copy,d);
```

Answer (score 1):

boolean is not a class but a primitive type.
In your function call you hand over the value false not a reference to the object.
Changing the value of paramenter in the function has no effect on the original boolean.

Comment: It would make no difference if `eq` were an object. It would enable changing of properties of the instance by invoking methods on it, but the `eq` inside the method would still be a *copy* of the reference: assigning to `eq` (e.g., `eq = null`) would have no effect outside the method.

Answer (score 1):

He just wanted to know why. I say give the solution to openCage. I can elaborate a little further on his answer with some links. If you want the variable to be passed by reference you can wrap it in a class([How do I pass a primitive data type by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319537/how-do-i-pass-a-primitive-data-type-by-reference/4319581#4319581)), but I would recommend the idea of simply returning the boolean value that rgettman mentions above.

Here is a link to the documentation on Java Primitives which are not implemented as classes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Because parameters in Java are passed by value

```
 int x = 1;
 fn(x);
 System.out.println(x); // nothing changed

 public void fn(int x){
     x++; // changes stay local to fn
 }
```

A common way to solve this is to return the value you changing

```
public int fn(int x){
   x++;
   return x;
}
```

and now you can assign the new value to x

```
int x = 1;
x = fn(x);
System.out.println(x); // it works now, Brilliant!
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `removeAccess` method you are setting local variable `eq` to true. It's the variable that was declared as a parameter that is being set.

You would want to declare `eq` outside of a method and make it a class member and just manipulate it inside of your methods. For the removeAccess method you can still accept it as a parameter but use `this.eq = eq;` to assign the argument value to the class variable. Once you have assigned the value, continue to use `this.eq`(class) to differentiate between the local `eq` and class `eq`.