# Changing the value of a primitive variable in a method?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, primitive-types

In Java, it is possible to declare a parameter of a primitive type (int, double ...) and change its value within the method. When the method is exited, is the value of the variable updated?

Comment: Assuming you want `int x = 1; makeItTwo(x); //now x is 2` then it is impossible since Java is always pass by value. Your best chance is `x=makeItTwo(x);` where `makeItTwo` *returns* new value.

Comment: See this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319537/how-do-i-pass-a-primitive-data-type-by-reference

Comment: You can cheat and make your parameter an `int[]` with length 1.

Comment: The simple answer to the question is no. A primitive parameter variable can indeed be manipulated within a method but since it is pass-by-value, the changes won't take effect outside the method. See the output of this example code: https://rextester.com/GYTK35410

Answer (score 2):

This is not simple, due to the way java handles parameters. Primitives (like `int` or `long`) are handed by value, `Objects` by reference. This means only `Objects` can be manipulated inside of methods and the changes will be visible outside of the method. If you want to get this behaviour, you'll have to use wrapper-classes:

```
class Wrapper<class T>{
    private T val;

    public Wrapper(T v){
        val = v;
    }

    public void setVal(T v){ val = v; }
    public T getVal(){ return val; }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that primitives can't be used as generic types so even if this approach is taken wrapper types would have to be used. new Wrapper<Long>(1L);